# Using HTTP proxy in domCrawler component of Symfony

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, http-proxy

I'm using DomCrawler component to make DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents.

When I use like that:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
```

I'll use my client IP to connect to google. Is there a way to use a proxy server for that connection to scrape HTML data masking my IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that way:

```
$client = new Client();
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config', ['curl' => [
        CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxyaddress:proxy",
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => "user:pass",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__). "/cookies.txt",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__). "/cookies.txt"
    ]
    ]);
```